# Sharing gmail can 'potentially' erase my device

Tags: factory-reset, gmail, android-device-manager

Me and my friend use shared email (about 15 people), then i realized from that gmail account i can see the connected phone (specially android), and i can play around with that (lock phone, ring) and **wipe out** the device / factory reset, and i thought this is so ridiculous, who would have thought sharing email account can do that much harm, to my question :

Can i select which gmail account (strictly personal account) have access to wipe my device and which not?

*edit: currently i had find my device setting disabled*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my phone be monitored by my family members without them ever accessing it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215527/can-my-phone-be-monitored-by-my-family-members-without-them-ever-accessing-it)

Comment: @alecxs nope, it is not

Comment: i recommend to remove the google account from phone settings and create a new one

Comment: Why don't you uninstall Find my Device, or deny it administrator privileges in settings? In that way, you shouldn't fear someone else erasing your device.